# EF.net Core async data loading into Observable

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, .net-core, observable

We have a particular situation with a WPF app. The viewmodel loads data (using ef.net) from a database over a bit-slower-than-usual link. It takes about 20 seconds for 1000 rows to be retrieved into a DataGrid and that sort of keeps the view empty until all of the data is loaded, at which point everything is dumped to the grid at once.

So the question is, can we somehow configure and/or use some way to get ef.net to async return an empty Observable which would then be streamed with data as it comes. Then we could bind that observable sourxe to grid and just stand aside.  Lots of resources on the net discuss ef.net in the context of disconnected service streaming already loaded data out (asp.net/res for example) and very little on in-context loading.

I would prefer to keep the solution within the realm of ef.net, without custom solutions leaning on ADO/etc cursors.

Comment: does loading 10 rows take less time? You can use pagination mechanisms to load chunks and then put the chunks in Observable so that grid loads them as they come

Comment: @mmix Have you tried [`DbSet.Local.ToObservableCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.localview-1.toobservablecollection?view=efcore-2.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_ChangeTracking_LocalView_1_ToObservableCollection)? See also [`DbSet.Local`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.local?view=efcore-2.1)

Comment: @JanPaoloGo I tried starting a background Load and then using Local as ObservableCollection. However the moment I called ToObservableCollection while Load() was happening in background, the EF threw an Exception. Some weird error with a foosnote that its probably because I issued anew command before the old one was completed.

Answer (score 0):

> can we somehow configure and/or use some way to get ef.net to async return an empty Observable which would then be streamed with data as it comes

No, not unless EF actually streams the results back but I guess it returns all records once they (all) have been fetched from the database.

You need an `IObservable` API to be able to do this but EF doesn't provide one. What you could possible do is to query for fewer items, load these into the observable or the source collection of the `DataGrid` directly, and then query for more items.

Comment: Yea, its seems more and more like this. I was just hoping that there might be some extensions or 3rd party plugins taht would provide this functionality.

Comment: I was hoping for something like this, but more directly supported. https://github.com/NickStrupat/EntityFramework.Rx